# QGIS HTML Widget

Tags: qgis, html, qgis-widget

I am looking at using the HTML widget in a drag n drop form to show a horizontal bar the length of which is based on a field. Not being a programmer of any sort I don't know the html syntax to use - a simple bar would be great but the widget isn't well documented - anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML widget accepts HTML language and JavaScript.

To get a value from a layer field, the following JS code is :

```html
<script>expression.evaluate("\"my_field\"")</script>
```

To build a simple horizontal bar in HTML (color red, length 75% of the total width of the page) :

```html
<div style='background-color:red; width:75%'>&nbsp;</div>
```

So, now, we will build HTML with JS by replacing values with JS variables :

```html
<p id="my_bar"></p>
<script>
var percent_length = expression.evaluate("\"my_length_field\"") / expression.evaluate("array_max(array_agg(\"my_length_field\"))") * 100;
var color = "#00FF00"
document.getElementById("my_bar").innerHTML = "<div style='background-color:" + color + "; width:" + percent_length + "%'>&nbsp;</div>";
</script>
```

Step-by-step :

- retrieve the current length from the field `"my_length_field"` : `expression.evaluate("\"my_length_field\"")`
- retrieve the max length value from this same field : `expression.evaluate("array_max(array_agg(\"my_length_field\"))")`
- get the current value in percent : `@current_value / @max_value * 100`
- store this percent length in a variable : `var percent_length =`
- store for more readability the bar color in a variable, here Lime : `var color = "#00FF00"`
- build the HTML horizontal bar code with the two variables : `"<div style='background-color:" + color + "; width:" + percent_length + "%'>&nbsp;</div>"`
- get the HTML paragraph identified as `"my_bar"` and replace its (empty) content (`innerHTML`) with the generated HTML code.

The result will be a Lime (super green) horizontal bar with a length varying between ]0 - 100] % of the width of the form dialog, according to your `"my_length_field"` value.

Comment: hey @j-monticolo there's any documantation that we can study for this? I know that some classes come from vanilla JS, but `expression.evaluate()` seems to be this one: <https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsExpression.html#qgis.core.QgsExpression.evaluate>

Comment: @See7e: without certitude, but as this is a QML widget, maybe it refers to : https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#evaluate